# Github Actions - No jobs defined in `jobs`

Tags: github-actions

I have written a simple Github action to check to see if my linting rules have been met whenever a PR is raised. But whenever I run it, I get the error message "No jobs defined in `jobs`". How can I fix this?

```
name: Check rules
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - develop
      - master
steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2
  - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
    with:
      node-version: '12'
      check-latest: true
  - run: npm install
  - run: npm check-rules
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per the error message, you need to define `jobs`.

```yaml
name: Check rules
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - develop
      - master
jobs:
    your_npm_job_name:
        steps:
          - uses: actions/checkout@v2
          - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
             with:
              node-version: '12'
              check-latest: true
          - run: npm install
          - run: npm check-rules
```

Comment: to be clear, so the outermost name is the action name, and we still need a jobs name.